# How to define a function pointer that returns a value?

Tags: rust, parameters, function-pointers

I would like to create a callback function. The following code is not working but it shows what I want to do. Here is the [link of my broken program in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c323d92764898ba6440e974bf7dae73).

```
fn use_callback(callback: fn()) -> i32 {
    callback()
}

fn callback() -> i32 {
    2
}

fn main() {
    println!("Result: {:?}", use_callback(callback));
}
```

The expected result should be `Result: 2`.

Comment: hint: how do you write the return type of a function?

Comment: Related: [How do you pass a Rust function as a parameter?](/q/36390665/2189130)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change the type of callback in the `use_callback` function to a function pointer that returns an `i32`.

```rust
fn use_callback(callback: fn() -> i32) -> i32 {
                           //  ^^^^^^ here 
    return callback();
}
fn callback() -> i32 {
    return 2;
}
fn main() {
    println!("Result: {:?}", use_callback(callback));
}
```

*[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=471dc750238958f61cf31ed4bd31a4ca)*